# не могу отсортировать массив для вывода категорий

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

есть некий массив items мне надо его отфильтровать по категориям , как сделать через цикл for или items.filter, я пробовал( index используется в React.Component onClick={() =>{productModel.typeOfProducts("phone")}}

```
items = [
    {
        id: 100,
        title: 'Ipnone 200',
        price: 12000,
        type:"phone",
        rest: 10
    },
    {
        id: 101,
        title: 'Samsung AAZ8',
        price: 22000,
        type:"phone",
        rest: 5
    },
    {
        id: 103,
        title: 'Nokia 3310',
        price: 5000,
        type:"phone",
        rest: 2
    },
    {
        id: 105,
        title: 'Huawei ZZ',
        price: 15000,
        type:"phone",
        rest: 8
    },
    {
        id: 106,
        title: 'Ipad 10',
        price: 20000,
        type:"tablet",
        rest: 8
    },
    {
        id: 107,
        title: 'ipad 20x',
        price: 15000,
        type:"tablet",
        rest: 8
    },
    {
        id: 108,
        title: 'Microwave',
        price: 5000,
        type:"appliance",
        rest: 8
    },
];

typeOfProducts(index){
    this.items.map((pr,i) =>{
        if(pr.type !== index){
            this.items.splice(i,1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: покажите пример входного массива и что вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` вернет столько же элементов, сколько в исходном массиве, а вам надо отобрать часть. Удобнее воспользоваться `filter` по условию `type` равен заданному

```js
items = [
    {
        id: 100,
        title: 'Ipnone 200',
        price: 12000,
        type:"phone",
        rest: 10
    },
    {
        id: 101,
        title: 'Samsung AAZ8',
        price: 22000,
        type:"phone",
        rest: 5
    },
    {
        id: 103,
        title: 'Nokia 3310',
        price: 5000,
        type:"phone",
        rest: 2
    },
    {
        id: 105,
        title: 'Huawei ZZ',
        price: 15000,
        type:"phone",
        rest: 8
    },
    {
        id: 106,
        title: 'Ipad 10',
        price: 20000,
        type:"tablet",
        rest: 8
    },
    {
        id: 107,
        title: 'ipad 20x',
        price: 15000,
        type:"tablet",
        rest: 8
    },
    {
        id: 108,
        title: 'Microwave',
        price: 5000,
        type:"appliance",
        rest: 8
    },
];

function typeOfProducts(arr, type) {
    return arr.filter(pr => pr.type == type)
    }
    
console.log(typeOfProducts(items, "phone"))
```